"С других" или "от других" – как правильно?
Увидела заголовок статьи – "Ароматы, которые я чаще всего ощущаю с других". Автора в комментариях упрекают, что заголовок неграмотно сформулирован. Задумалась: вроде нормально сказано, и, по-моему, есть смысловой нюанс между "с других" и "от других", если речь идет о запахах. А как на самом деле правильно?

Ответ изменен
Можно  так: Ароматы окружающих, которые я чаще всего ощущаю.
Пояснение
Управление глагола ощущать (что от кого?) – от других людей сомнительно, хотя возможно ощущать (что от чего?) для неодуш. предметов. Вариант "ощущать с кого-либо" также некорректен.
Но можно использовать управление существительного (беспредложное или с предлогом ОТ): ароматы кого или ароматы от кого. Беспредложное управление выглядит предпочтительнее.
ГРАММАТИКА на  примере с цветами

Беспредложное управление Р.п., качественная характеристика: аромат цветов, цветочный аромат.

Управление  Р.п. с предлогами ОТ и С


Способность управления существительные получают, участвуя в реализации  глагольной связи: Цветы источают аромат — аромат исходит от цветов — аромат, исходящий от цветов — аромат от цветов.
Управление, предлог ОТ: аромат от цветов (от объекта, пространственное значение)
Управление, предлог С: запахи с лугов (с поверхности чего-либо, пространственное значение).
Ветер доносит аромат с цветущих лугов.
Итак, грамматический вывод: аромат/запах от окружающих (от объекта) в принципе возможен, но нельзя сказать аромат/запах с объекта. Здесь возможно значение  с пространства, где расположен объект.
Источник: Русская грамматика под ред. Шведовой Н.Ю и Лопатина В.В, 1990 год, однотомник
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Или же глаз испытывает раздражение, какое мы ощущаем от острого блюда.
Я обожал этот запах, где ароматы от кафе и ресторанов перемешиваются с ароматами людей и машин, деревьев и старых московских улиц.
Карта слов
Сочетаемость словосочетания «ощущать от»
Сочетаемость словосочетания «аромат от»
Сочетаемость слова «аромат»
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
 АРОМАТ, -а; м. [от греч. arōmatós - душистое 
 вещество]. 1. Приятный запах, благоухание. А. 
 духов. Источать тонкий а. Повеяло ароматами весны. 
 2. только мн.: ароматы, -ов. Устар. Душистые 
 вещества, пряности. Сухие ароматы. * Не жалей ни 
 вин моих, ни ароматов (Пушкин). 3. чего. Высок. 
 Едва уловимый, но характерный отличительный 
 признак чего-л. А. юности. Ароматный (см.).


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

«На бесконечные усы лились восточны ароматы.» Пушкин.
"Ароматы, которые я чаще всего ощущаю с других".
1)_Ароматы не ощущают, а вдыхают. Вообще аромат это как жидкость, он льётся, распространяется и тп. Можно погружаться в аромат, но ощущать аромат почему-то не говорят, наверное, можно ощущать ароматный запах. То есть аромат, это не совсем запах, а то, что является причиной запаха, как вода является причиной влажности. Не говорят же "ощущаю воду".
2)_Не говорят "ощущаю с других". Вообще у меня сомнения по поводу употребления предлога с "ощущаю", если это не "ощущаю с трепетом", например. "Ощущаю от" не менее криво. Единственное сочетание которое встречается в литературе это фразы вида "ощущают от того":

Я все так же, как и всегда прежде, могу пожелать сделать доброе дело и
ощущаю от того удовольствие; рядом желаю и злого и тоже чувствую
удовольствие. Достоевский

И также "ощущать" с предлогами может быть использовано при описании чувств(ощущаю холод от них), а данном в предложении этого тоже нет.
Ещё можно добавить:
"Ощущаю оттуда/с того голоса" не говорят. Хотя допустимо "слышу оттуда голоса."
С ароматом примерно тоже происходит, не достаточно сказать "ощущаю", но если уточнить - слышу, вдыхаю, пью, - тогда можно составить ряд.
Хотя даже тут не все имеет место быть, потому что "вдыхать от" и производные - отсутствуют на НКРЯ совершенно; "вдыхать с" - встречается редко, но кстати:

Я прислушивался к монотонному стрекотанию кузнечиков в парке и вдыхал
с жадностью нежный аромат цветов, волны которого лились в окно. Октав
Гудайль в Ясной Поляне (1891).
Они тихо стали прогуливаться по берегу, вдыхая с наслаждением
ароматный воздух... Гейнце;

предлог "с" со словом "вдыхая" употребляется сразу с качественным прилагательным;
насчёт "слышу от" - употребление частое, но:

Я слышу от многих разсуждающих, что оное Уложенье нуждно вновь делать.
Татищев.
Слышу от нее похвалы и телесным и духовным качествам, которыми я, по
ее словам, наделен.Романов;

то есть предлог "от" предполагает не просто "голос или аромат", а подробное разъяснение, что слышится, как слышится, вероятно какая-то оценка. То есть:
"Ароматы парфюма, которые я чаще всего слышу от других." - вероятно, такая фраза была бы корректна;
И насчёт "слышу с", употребимо, но предлог "с" ставит написанное далее в позицию обстоятельства места), я не уверен, что "других" можно посчитать за место:

Вдруг слышу крик подле меня, слышу с завода люди бегут. Достоевский.


Спасибо за ответ. Насчет "Ароматы не ощущают, а вдыхают" – спорно. Едет человек, допустим, в метро, со всех сторон ощущает (чувствует? слышит?) ненавистный ему аромат духов "Кирке".
Также и насчет ""ощущать" с предлогами может быть использовано при описании чувств". Обоняние – это же чувство.

Аромат как слово не связано напрямую с обонянием, аромат - это не запах, по крайней мере так получается из текстов, которые есть на НКРЯ.
"АРОМА́Т, аромата, муж. (греч. aroma - всё благоухающее)."
Душистые вещества. «На бесконечные усы лились восточны ароматы.» Пушкин.
Аромат он не вдыхается, если не указано это, он льётся. То есть в слове аромат нет обязательного указания, что его ощущают с помощью обоняния. Это странный момент, но такова особенность этого слова. Аромат приравнивается к среде и жидкости, возможно "эфиру", который отменили, а не к газу.

Если вы добавите глагол вдыхает, слышит, или подобный, то да, вы свяжите аромат с запахом. Но если просто "ощущение", то этого не достаточно для указания, что с ароматом происходит.
Вы же не говорите: "ощущаю оттуда голос"; хотя "слышу оттуда голоса" - уже возможно. Слышу голос с других, слышу голос от других - уже криво.

Аромат – это и есть запах (у Ожегова, Ушакова "аромат – Душистый, приятный запах,"), поэтому логично, что запах (и аромат, как его разновидность) связан с обонянием. Чувствовать (ощущать) запах – воспринимать обонянием. И необязательно добавлять "слышит" или "вдыхает".

Фразу приведите из литературы, тогда будет смысл. Словарь не полностью отражает особенности употребления. Я вам привёл литературные примеры как употребления слова аромат, так и слов связанных с ним с предлогами. Там проблема не в одном слове АРОМАТ, в этой фразе сразу много проблем.

— И вдобавок пьян! — с веселым изумлением к постоянству Феногеновых привычек сказал Николай, ощутив запах водки.
Андреев Л. Н., В тёмную даль, 1900
И тонкие ноздри его ясно ощущали запах гнили и распада, идущий от той свободы, по которой томился Достоевский.
Вересаев В. В., Живая жизнь, 1914
Он снял с нее шубу и калоши и в это время ощутил запах белого вина, того самого, которым она любила запивать устриц
Чехов А. П., Супруга, 1895

Его думы нарушил появившийся Яков с лодносом в руках. На подносе лежало письмо. Граф взял его и ощутил аромат тех знакомых духов, от которых у него всегда так сильно билось сердце.
Гейнце Н. Э., Коронованный рыцарь, 1895
Ипполит Сергеевич молча поклонился ей и, пожимая её руку, обнажённую до локтя, ощутил нежный аромат фиалок, исходивший от неё.
Горький Максим, Варенька Олесова, 1896
Но Галя не слышала пения ангелов, не чувствовала аромата цветов.
Чарская Л. А., Галина правда, 1912

@YuiiyaVlady Аромат знакомых духов, аромат фиалок, нежный аромат цветов. Аромат не употребляется без указания аромат чего или какой. И заметьте, нигде нет предложных конструкций вроде "аромат от цветов" или "ощутил от цветов". Поэтому я добавил слово к аромат - ароматы парфюма, и поправил употребление предлога.

Изначально именно ароматы парфюма и подразумевались. Меня больше интересовало "с других"/"от других".

@YuiiyaVlady "c" - предлог обстоятельства места, вы можете "других" сделать обстоятельством места? Слово ощутить практически не употреблятся таким образом с предлогами, тем более в связке с аромат. Потому что аромат==запах, а ощутить == вдохнуть. Ощутить больше связано с ощупать.

Извините, вмешаюсь в разговор. Интересная статья:  Почему аромат слушают, а не нюхают https://www.sunscents.ru/blog/aromaty/aromat-slushayut    Выражение «слушать аромат» вошло в обиход еще в середине 19 века с подачи английского химика Джорджа Уилсона Пиесса. Ученый первым начал ассоциировать ароматы веществ с нотными гаммами и тем самым романтизировал парфюмерное дело.  И т. д.

@Sharon ох уж эти англосаксы, везде они первые... нет: "В 10 часу вечера, сидя в моей каюте, я услышал запах дыма;" 1822 год. Уилсону было 2 года на тот момент) Но вполне вероятно, что слышать ~ различать. А ощущать - это воспринимать без различения. Аромат - это сладковатый или пряный запах, с акцентом на "пряный", а не на "запах", то есть уже включает в себя необходимость различия, употреблять его с "ощущать" некорректно.

@Буратино вы пишете: ""c" - предлог обстоятельства места, вы можете "других" сделать обстоятельством места? " – а как же "с тобой/со мной/с ними"? Тут предлог "с" употребляется на каких основаниях?

@YuiiyaVlady ладно, тут дело не совсем в обстоятельстве места, но "с тобой" - это в+месте с тобой. С других, с них и тп. употребимо, когда речь идёт о чём-то, что забрали с- и перенесли к-. Пчела собрала пыльцу с цветка(взяла себе, перенёсла с цветка на себя или с цветка в улей). А каким образом можно аромат-запах взять себе? Можно только указать направление откуда - от других.

Да, такой оттенок действительно есть. Если порассуждать, то "с" несёт некоторый принудительный, насильственный оттенок.
Сравните:

Деньги с бабули (явно вытрясли)
Деньги от бабули (точно получили добровольно)

Ещё:

Шапка с соболя (криво, лучше бы подошло "из", но всё же ясно, что животное убили)
Шапка от соболя (кажется, соболь шапку-то просто подарил)

Дальше:

Запчасть с машины (явно сняли из машины)
Запчасть от машины (в такой формулировке она вполне может продаваться ДЛЯ машины)

Таким образом, "с" интуитивно подразумевает, что мы нечто забираем, часто принудительно. А вот "от" предлог "добровольный", "мягкий", он не режет слух и не создаёт негативных ассоциаций.
Даже если представить человека, который нюхает "с людей", и человека, который нюхает "от людей", это две разные картины: один грубо впихивается в личное пространство, чтобы нюхнуть прохожих, а другой вполне может просто с удовольствием ловить запахи на расстоянии. Всё те же оттенки грубости/насильственности и мягкости/добровольности.
